# Pivot Slicer Update To Slow, Can I pause all functions until slicer update is complete? VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button click item on my spreadsheet that sets a slicer with the appropriate supervisors per location. The problem is it takes too long. After every change on the slicer like setting "Smith" to true the entire workbook recalculates all the formulas before moving to the next item. Can I pause all of the formulas in my workbook until the last item is set and then re enable them.

```
Sub Rectangle_Click()
 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Supervisor1").ClearManualFilter
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Supervisor1")
        .SlicerItems("Smith").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Fox").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Dougan").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Milton").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Johnson").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Johnsen").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Jones").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("Davis").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("Miller").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Moore").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Taylor").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("Anderson").Selected = True
    End With
    Call Auto_SortAndFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used the .SlicerItems method so I don't know how it might affect that, however, I think you just want to put your code within these two commands.

```
Application.Calculation = xlmanual 
Application.Calculation = xlautomatic
```

N